# Open Androidx86 system.img to edit init.sh

Tags: android-x86

I have been trying to open the system.img on my Androidx86 installation to add `rmmod i2c-hid` and `modprobe i2c-hid` to it because the touch on my Tablet doesn't seem to work in Android x86. I have already tried to open it with EXT4 Unpacker, but it says Unknown file format when I try to open the system.img.

I am on Windows 7 32 bit right now.

Any suggestions, guys?

Comment: While this is on topic here you may find a better response on [android.se].

Comment: You can raise a moderator flag and they will move this one for you.

Answer (score 2):

in my experience, use this trick

1. just install the android os, and boot
2. open  `root folder/etc/init.sh` and copy `init.sh`
3. copy to another location and open using text editor
4. add `rmmod i2c-hid` and the `modprobe i2c` inside the function `init_misc` , make sure you just place the code and dont edit another code inside it, save in location you wanted
5. press `alt+f1` and  type `cat /etc/init.sh > /(location you placed the edited init.sh)`

sory for my english
hope it help you